# chrome mac browser size displays wrong value

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Developing a worpress site I encounters issues with media queries in css. What I discovered is that Safari, Firefox and Opera displays the right values. (When I maximize my screen the browser size and the viewport size gives me a value of 1920 px) Chrome however gives me a value of 1280 px. Working with Chrome version 40.0.2214.93 (64-bit). The difference is that big that I ruled the scrollbar sizes out. Next to that is Safari (a webkit browser also) displaying it right.

It is really annoying to see the media queries are kicking in on the wrong pixel according to chrome.
Anyone an idea?

Comment: chrome 40 is buggy, upgrade to 41

Comment: @rachel, thank you for commenting. I downloaded 41 beta but that does not did the trick. And suddenly it hits me (and I'm blushing of shame) I was viewing the site at 110% so the measurements were 10% of. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: oops" oh well we all make mistakes!!! check your zoom next time :)

Comment: Yeah, but mistakes like this ....... hmmpfffff :)